# on conflict mutation gives unexpected result

Tags: hasura

on_conflict returns unknown argument

new to hasura, tried looking at multiple how to on_conflict, ran mutation from api explorer and from frontend, tried upsert_users (suggest me to change it to insert)

```
mutation upsert_users {
 insert_users(
    objects: [{
    auth0_id: "iexistindb", 
    name: "somename"}
  ], 
  on_conflict: {
  constraint: users_pkey, 
  update_columns: [last_seen, name]
  }
) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

expected to update the user table if auth0 already exist

Comment: solved: used the api explorer analyze, i need to add admin access to enable on conflict mutation.

Comment: Can you add this as the answer to your own question? This will help someone else who has this problem? Thanks!

Comment: i will tried to figure it out rather new to stackoverflow, but thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1):

so i just encountered this now. i had the on_conflict / update_columns but hadn't given update permissions to the role, only insert

Comment: You can accept your own answer so it will not be in not-answered